# What is the difference between the two methods used in finding CDF?

Tags: probability, random-variables

In [**this video**](https://youtu.be/4BswLMKgXzU) the author talks about 3 methods of converting a PDF into CDF.

- Method-1 is discussed from [06:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BswLMKgXzU&t=380s)
- Method-2 is discussed from [09:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BswLMKgXzU&t=580s)
- Method-3 is discussed from [14:22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BswLMKgXzU&t=862s)

Method-1 is about using geometry. I understand the Method-1 and already hating it.  My question is about the rest of the two methods.

Method-2 is using definite integral, and Method-3 is using indefinite integral.

Apart from that, I don't see any difference.

Is there any other difference between the last two methods used in finding CDF?

Comment: For me, this is just a consequence of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and I view them as the *same*.

Comment: I guess that method 2 is using the additive property of integrals, i.e. $\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_b^c f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_a^c f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$. Whereas method 3 is selecting the solutions of the indefinite integrals such that the properties of the CDF are satisfied.

Comment: @TimothyHedgeworth, kindly post this as a complete answer. I will accept that.

Comment: @user366312 It is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2 implicitly uses the additive property of integrals, i.e.
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_b^cf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, $$
whereas method 3 selects the solutions of the indefinite integrals such that properties of the CDF are satisfied.